# Cannot install wine because of broken dependency

Tags: 11.04, wine, dependencies, package-management

I am trying to install wine on a 64-bit Natty.

It was installed, but one of my regular `update` & `dist-upgrade`s removed it (didn't pay enough attention to which packages would be removed).

Now when I'm trying to install it, I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.3 but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: ia32-libs (>= 1.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58455/cannot-install-wine-on-ubuntu-natty-64bit-broken-dependency) on askubuntu, but the accepted answer (change the mirror to the main one) didn't work for me.

I also tried to disable all sources that aren't enabled after a clean install, do an `update` an install wine, didn't work.

Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list` (sans comments for brewity):

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main universe restricted multiverse 

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main universe restricted multiverse

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main universe restricted multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security universe

deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu natty main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libv4l/ppa/ubuntu natty main

deb http://apt.mucommander.com stable main non-free contrib

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ natty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ natty partner
```

And here's the contents of the files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gm-notify-maintainers/ppa/ubuntu natty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gm-notify-maintainers/ppa/ubuntu natty main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mozillateam/firefox-next/ubuntu natty main

deb http://deb.opera.com/opera/ stable non-free

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/resmo/git-ftp/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/resmo/git-ftp/ubuntu natty main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tualatrix/ppa/ubuntu natty main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu natty main
```

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies? `ia32-libs`?. Also to install wine is `apt-get install wine1.3` or `wine1.2` for the stable version, `wine` is to actually execute the program, so `apt-get install wine` will not work.

Comment: `ia32` is one of the dependencies that cannot be installed. If it could be, apt-get would have handled that for me automatically. `ia32-libs` depends on `lib32v4l-0`, and there's no suck package at all. Also: wine is actually a metapackage that depends on wine1.3 if you have the wine ppa installed (see the top: `wine depends on wine1.3`).

Comment: I just downloaded `ia32-libs` as a .deb from packages.ubuntu.com but it cannot be installed because `lib32v4l-0` is missing. Also did a search for that, that package is oneiric-only.

Comment: I mean install the oneiric package.I guess you already tried to just install `wine1.3` instead of the meta package?.

Comment: I didn't realize I could install oneiric packages on natty, but that seems to have worked, wine is being installed right now. Please add your solution as an answer and I shall accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By installing the missing `ia32-libs` the problem can be reoslved as it's a missing dependency, the OP had encountered that `ia32-libs`depends on `lib32v4l-0` but the package is only available for Oneiric.

Installing the .deb for `lib32v4l-0` solves the dependencies for `ia32-libs` which in turn solves the dependency for `wine`.

Comment: Actually, on oneiric `ia32-libs` provides `libv4l32-0`, so that's the only package I needed.